# Javascript strings with keyword parameters

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, keyword

I miss so much a simple feature present on ruby on rails: strings keyword parameters, like this:

```
"the key '%{key}' has a value of '%{value}'" % {:key => 'abc', :value => 5}
```

In javascript you have to sum many strings making the code uggly and hard to write.

Is there a good library for this? I'm not interested in something like sprintf.

Comment: What about a templating engine like [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)?

Comment: This is a micro optimization issue. Focus on something more concrete in my opinion.

Comment: There are [underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template), but that might be overkill for you.

Comment: [coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) let's you do stuff like `"Yo #{name}, have you checked out #{languageThatCompilesToJavascript}?"` Just saying :)

Comment: @bfvaretto a template system is too much for a simple string substitution. already using underscore templating

Comment: @TravisJ How is this a micro-optimization? This is about readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String.prototype.format = function(obj) {
  return this.replace(/%\{([^}]+)\}/g,function(_,k){ return obj[k] });
};

"the key '%{key}' has a value of '%{value}'".format({ key:'abc', value:5 });
```

Comment: you should call it something else though, since a native "".format is on the docket for ecma6 by doug crockford...

Answer (score 0):

You could make a basic array-type formatter:

```
String.prototype.format = function(args) {
    var str = this,
        idxRx = new RegExp("{[0-9]+}", "g");
    return str.replace(idxRx, function(item) {
        var val = item.substring(1, item.length - 1),
            intVal = parseInt(val, 10),
            replace;
        replace = args[intVal];
        return replace;
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
'{1} {0} and {2}!'.format(["collaborate", "Stop", "listen"])
// => 'Stop collaborate and listen!'
```

Comment: You could reduce all that to `return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g,function(_,n){ return args[+n] });`. Usually you'd do this with the `arguments` array tho, so you can just pass infinite number of arguments and map it to the placeholders, instead of using an additional array.